# Pass object from view to controller MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, ajax.beginform

I need to pass this object from the view to the controller:

```
public class QuoteVehicle
    {
        [DisplayName("Quote Vehicle ID")]
        public int QuoteVehicleID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Quote ID")]
        public int QuoteID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Model Year")]
        public string ModelYear { get; set; }            
        //etc...
    }
```

If I set values in the controller, they are passed to the view; but if I set or change values in the view and pass it back... it gets there, but the values are null.

I'm using this Ajax.BeginForm:

```
 @Using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetQuote", "Quote", 
         New With {.QuoteVehicle = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.QuoteVehicle)},
         New AjaxOptions() With {
                                 .UpdateTargetId = "PriceOptionsPanel",
                                 .HttpMethod = "GET",
                                 .OnComplete = "SetDatePickers",
                                 .InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                 .LoadingElementId = "loader"
                                 }
))
```

my properties are bound as such inside the form:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.QuoteVehicle.Make, New With {.class = "form-control", .readonly = "readonly"})
```

and in my controller:

```
 Function GetQuote(QuoteVehicle As String) As ActionResult
    Dim _quoteVehicle = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of QuoteVehicle)(QuoteVehicle)
    Return View(etc.)
 End Function
```

I've also tried `<HttpPost>` and `.HttpMenthod = "POST"`, but that didn't work either.

Love to know why they're not being set...

The model looks like this:

```
Public Class MenuOptionsModel       
        Public Property VIN() As String
        Public Property QuoteVehicle() As QuoteVehicle
        Public Property IsDecoded As Boolean       
        Public Property IsNew As Boolean = False
        Public Property Is30Day As Boolean?
        Public Property IsUnderWarranty As Boolean?
    etc...
End Class
```

properties that are not in an object, but just types (i.e. Boolean?, String) bind fine, but properties within the object do not.

Comment: Why are you wanting to post back exactly the same object you just sent from the server?

Comment: Why wouldn't I? The object is in the model... I need to fill that object with the data from the view - how else would I pass that info? 20 separate fields?

Comment: I don't think you understand - your serializing the model on the server, sending it to the client, and sending back exactly the same model, not anything that has been edited. Remove your 3rd parameter of `BeginForm()` and change the method parameter to be you model, not a `string`

Comment: And based on your edit - it needs to be `GetQuote(model As MenuOptionsModel)`

Comment: When I do that the model is null...

Comment: Then you have other errors. If you send a model which is typeof `MenuOptionsModel` to the view, and generate your form controls correctly using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods, and the model in the POST method is the same then it will be bound correctly. Possible reasons for not binding are, your model contains fields not properties, the name of the parameter is the same as one of the model properties, or you creating an input for a complex object. Does your model contain a property named `model`?

Comment: DOH! Okay boys and girls... don't name the property you want to pass the same name as your object - i.e. "Public QuoteVehicle As QuoteVehicle". I renamed the property to "Public CurrentQuoteVehicle As QuoteVehicle" and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out that you can't name your object for what your object is, like:

```
Public QuoteVehicle As QuoteVehicle
```

And then use it like:

```
Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", New With { .QuoteVehicle = Model.QuoteVehicle...

Function GetQuote(QuoteVehicle As QuoteVehicle) As ActionResult
   //access properties
End Function
```

All I had to do was rename the property to something that wasn't EXACTLY like the object's type/name... like:

```
Public _quoteVehicle As QuoteVehicle    
Public NotNamedQuoteVehicle As QuoteVehicle
etc...
```

I used `Public CurrentQuoteVehicle As QuoteVehicle`

And now this works:

```
Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", New With { .CurrentQuoteVehicle = Model.QuoteVehicle...

Function GetQuote(CurrentQuoteVehicle As QuoteVehicle) As ActionResult
   //access properties
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

change your action param type to  QuoteVehicle  and use HttpPost and .HttpMenthod = "POST"

```
 Function GetQuote(model As QuoteVehicle ) As ActionResult
  //now you can access to your model here
    Return View(etc.)
 End Function
```